# Create a Gradle setup to publish dependency with source code on Jitpack ? (Gradle 5.6.2)

Tags: java, gradle, jitpack

I want to publish a small library and I have a hard time to finde a solution to publish my sources alongside the dependency on jitpack.io .

The class files are available but nothing else.

This is my Gradle file:

```
plugins {

    id 'java-library'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

repositories {

    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
//Problem part
task sourceJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: classes) {
    classifier 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
    archives javadocJar
}
//Problem part 
dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-jre'
    compile group: 'org.xerial', name: 'sqlite-jdbc', version: '3.28.0'
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
    compile group: 'org.reflections', name: 'reflections', version: '0.9.11'    

}
```

Is there something wrong with my Gradle file or does anyone has a suggestion, where I can look up this issue?

Comment: Instead of including the answer to your question in the question itself, you should rather add an answer. There's no need to delete the question, maybe it helps others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a Publishing configuration.

Just replace the tasks and the artifacts with:

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
    archiveClassifier.set("sources")
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
     archiveClassifier.set("javadoc")
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}

publishing {
      publications {
          mavenAar(MavenPublication) {
                from components.java
                afterEvaluate {
                    artifact javadocJar
                    artifact sourcesJar
                }
          }
     }
}
```

And now you can publish/release on Github via Jitpack.io and it will attach ressources and documentation.